# tf Variable does not change value?

Tags: tensorflow

i just want to change the value of a tf.Variable with .assign(), but it always prints "0" ?

```
import tensorflow as tf

session = tf.Session()

var = tf.Variable(0, "myVar")

session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

var.assign(var + 1)
print session.run(var)

var.assign(var + 1)
print session.run(var)
```

Edit: this works

```
import tensorflow as tf

session = tf.Session()

var = tf.Variable(0, "myVar")

session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

add = var.assign(var + 1)
print session.run(add)

print session.run(add)
```

Comment: I'm absolutely clueless on this, but as a punt, does `var = var.assign(var + 1)` work?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable    here they do it also

Answer (score 4):

assign only creates the operation to change the variable, you have to run it:

```
import tensorflow as tf

session = tf.Session()

var = tf.Variable(0, "myVar")

session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

session.run(var.assign(var + 1))
print session.run(var)

session.run(var.assign(var + 1))
print session.run(var)
```

Comment: cool another shorter way, thanks